# Is it possible to "freeze" applications so that they do not run unless "unfrozen" - essentially make them work only when they're in the foreground?

Tags: storage, privacy

What it says on the tin.

I'm used to a work partition, but since recent android versions don't support the required storage permissions (which means that I can't get data out of the work partition short of a root terminal) I have to install chat applications in my main profile.

I don't like how applications like Whatsapp run in the background constantly, and am trying to find a way to freeze them, so they only run when they're in the foreground.

I'm using Android 11.

Comment: Have you tried to just disable background network access for e.g. Whatsapp? You will still receive push notifications for new messages but Whatsapp will not be able to retrieve the actual message when it is in background.

Comment: What you describe is essentially what apps like [Insular](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.oasisfeng.island.fdroid/) (no trackers), its PlayStore sibling [Island](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.island) (with trackers) or [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) (also trackers; all 3 apps from the same dev) are doing. You can find some more candidates [in my listing here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batterysaver).

Comment: @Robert I don't want it running in the background.

Comment: @Izzy I was using shelter before I upgraded to android 11 (from 9).  My previous config carried over but none of the applications could access files, so I had to stop using it.  There's also no option to share files with the main profile, which is a dealbreaker for me.

Comment: Ah, yes – there were "breaking changes" with Android 11. I wasn't aware they could have effect here. Yes, Shelter can isolate apps, and then this might come up. I only remember having used Greenify ages ago and it simply "froze" apps when you didn't use them. Titanium Backup could do something similar "on demand" via a widget, but that needs a rooted device.